# Shape of waves in waveguide

Tags: waveguide

What is actually going on in waveguide when the wave is passing through it ? 
If I am not mistaking , the plane waves are "fed" to the waveguide and there is a cutoff freq above which the waves can pass. 
Now I want to visualise the whole picture. As far as I know , the plane waves have flux densities having sinusoidal variations. How these variations are related to modes in waveguide ? 
I am not able to fully understand the modes in waveguide..Plz help me out on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of waveguide?

Comment: I don't like to think about what the field is actually doing vs time. But for me, I envision that the photons (not waves) do not travel straight in the waveguide. They travel zig-zag fashion, bouncing off of the walls. Maxwells equations determine what frequency of photons can travel in a given waveguide, and what angles of bounce will allow the photons to travel rather than be reflected or absorbed or whatever. Also, this helps explain propagation speed (which is slower than propagation speed in free space). However it may not be physically accurate at all.

Answer (score 1):

The walls of the waveguide place some requirements on what kinds of waves can exist within the guide.  These are requirements on the value of the fields and how the fields are changing with distance in the guide. It becomes a math problem to then figure out what shapes are compatible with the shape of the guide.

For example: The walls of the waveguide short out any electric field on them ( the are conductive). Considering single frequency sine waves, long wavelengths will not have zero voltages at the walls. These frequencies are below the “cutoff” for the guide. The frequency must be high enough so there are some zero crossings at the walls. Only these higher frequencies can exist within the guide.

Answer (score 1):

Visualizing modes are hard. It requires us to visualize changing vector fields in three dimension. They are the "resonances" that your waveguide effectively propagate. Check Pozar o how to calculate them. In order to visualize them, I really had found this java applet to be helpful:

https://www.falstad.com/embox/guide.html

Given these modes, any linear superposition of them can propagate in the waveguide.